# Powershell :passing arg to scriptblock started with start-process

Tags: powershell

**[EDIT]:** One commenter said he was unable to make sense of my question and asked me to try to clarify.  I'll leave the original post below the line, and try again to explain it more succinctly in this edit

I want to create a function called `Run-Elevated`. It takes a scriptblock, and it executes it for you with elevated permissions.  I It it's not even very hard; this will do it:

```
# run.ps1
function RunElevated {
    param([scriptblock]$callback)
    Start-Process -FilePath powershell "-Command $callback" -Verb RunAs
}
```

Example usage:

```
# myscript.ps1

. ".\run.ps1"

RunElevated -callback {
    Write-Host "I am running with elevated permissions"
    Read-Host "Pause"
}
```

And it works! Easy peasy right?  Not exactly. For a super simple case like this yes, but the problem comes when `myscript.ps1` is updated and takes in an argument. In such a case, the `-callback` script block won't have access to the args passed into `myscript.ps1`.

That's the crux of the problem. If you add something like this to the `myscript.ps1` file:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [System.String]$name
)
```

Then, inside the `-callback` script block, you won't be able to access `$name`.  Is there a simple way to do it?  Because as you can see from my original post, it does seem possible, but it is decidedly *not* simple :-)

---

### Original post:

I've found several similar but not-quite-the-same questions on StackOverflow. Some of them were very helpful and allowed me to cobble together what I have presently, but I'm hopeful some of the Powershell experts out there can enlighten me.  Is there a better way?

Background:
Run.ps1 - Exposes a Run function which needs to take a callback that it will execute on behalf of the caller. It needs to execute the callback with elevated permissions

Main.ps1 - Script that takes a param, $name and imports Run.ps1 and calls Run, passing in the callback to be run

Script1.ps1 - Simple script that takes a param, $theName, and writes it to the screen

The challenge:
The challenge I've been having is that the Callback in Main.ps1, needs to be able to access $name from within the Callback, but it seems that it can't because Run.ps1 is executing it within the context of a new process? (That's my guess anyway)

I've tried literally dozens of different ways, but what I have below is all I could come up with that actually worked

```
# Main.ps1
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [System.String]$name
)

$cwd = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
. "$cwd\run.ps1"

Write-Host "name (outside) = $name"

Run -arguments @($name) -callbackName "callback" -context {
  function callback([string]$name2)
  {
    Write-Host "name2 inside callback = $name2"
    Read-Host "Pause"

    . .\script2.ps1 -theName $name2

    Read-Host "Pause"
  }
}
```

```
# Run.ps1
function Run {
    param (
        [scriptblock]$context,
        [string]$callbackName,
        [array]$arguments
    )
    
    $argsList = @("-NoProfile", "-ExecutionPolicy", "ByPass", "-Command", $context, $callbackName) + $arguments
    Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -ArgumentList $argsList -Verb RunAs -Wait
}
```

```
# Script1.ps1
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [System.String]$theName
)

Write-Host "theName is: $theName"
Read-Host "All done!"
```

When main is called from a PS command line, as in:
`./main.ps1 -name SomePerson`

The above works. "SomePerson" is passed from Main to Run, which then passes it back to the callback inside of main, which it then forwards on to Script1

But I really hate that it requires passing $context and $callbackName. It feels hacky.

I really want a solution that looks like this:

```
# Main.ps1
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [System.String]$name
)

$cwd = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
. "$cwd\run.ps1"

Write-Host "name (outside) = $name"

Run -callabck {
  Write-Host "name inside callback = $name" # $name not available here
  Read-Host "Pause"

  . .\script2.ps1 -theName $name

  Read-Host "Pause"
}
```

It seems there is no way to create a closure around $name.  I tried `.GetNewClosure()` but no dice. Maybe has something to do with different processes and how they interplay, which I clearly do not fully understand.

Is there any simpler way to do this?  The key criteria which are non-negotiable:

1. Run must execute the given callback with elevated permissions (I don't want a solution that takes another *file* and runs that with elevated permission.
2. The callback needs to either be able to access the parameters passed into the script in which it lives, or
3. The callback needs a way to accept params.  I'd prefer to avoid #3 (I'm already doing it, and it's convoluted) because it requires passing args to Run and then having Run pass them back into the callback, which feels round-about.

Appreciate any advice/tips/tricks (I'm clearly no powershell guru!)

Comment: I’ve tried several times to make sense of what you’re trying to do without success. Perhaps you can explain more of what you’re actually trying to do? Tbh it sounds like you are really overcomplicating things.

Comment: @DougMaurer, thanks for replying.  I left the original post, but I added an edit to the top where I attempt to more succinctly and more clearly explain the core issue.  Let me know if this makes any more sense?

Comment: Your ```RunElevated ``` function might take a scriptblock as a parameter, but it's being converted into a *string* that contains the source code of the scriptblock when it's being referenced in ```"-Command $callback"``` - ignoring the elevation for a moment it's logically equivalent to running this command in a Windows Command Prompt: ```"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command Write-Host "I am running with elevated permissions" Read-Host "Pause""``` (you can see this if you look in Task Manager with the "Command Line" column visible.

Comment: The child PowerShell process can't access the state of the parent PowerShell process - they're completely separate applications as far as Windows / PowerShell are concerned so you can't pass actual variables between them, reference parents scopes, apply closures, etc between the two processes - all you have in the child process is the string passed as the ```-Command``` parameter, which in your case is the string that contains the literal source code *text* of your scriptblock..

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the explanation!  So what I want to do is seemingly impossible. Yet, in a round about way that I’ve cobbled together, I have managed to get something that works. If you look at the original post, you’ll see it. I guess my next question would be: how exactly is that working? I found part of the technique on another stack overflow question - the part that seems to invoke the context (script block) and then execute a function (by name) that was defined within that scriptblock. Can you shed any light on the mechanism by which this works?

Comment: OH! I just re-read your comment and I think I understand better now.  Since it is the literal source code *text* of the scriptblock, that actually explains why it works to put a named function in that scriptblock and then invoke that function from the -Command passed into Start-Process. I just wondering if this too hacky to consider, or if it actually makes sense.  I didn't come up with it.  I found it in an answer on another stack overflow; I merely adapted it for my needs.  Hmm...

Comment: I can do something like this, but it's really a string, not a script block.  `start-process -wait powershell "echo $name" -nonewwindow`.  It will reflect whatever $name is set to.

Comment: Here’s a simple repro to show the difference - ```$name = "aaa"; write-host { "name = $name" }; write-host "name = $name"``` - the first write-host outputs the *source code (text)* of the script block, but the second *evaluates* (interpolates) the string and outputs the result. In your original code you’re passing the first version to ```-Command``` and in your “working” version you’re appending the *value* of the ```$name``` variable into the command after the script block text similar to the second write-host.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that works for me:

```
function RunElevated {
    param([string]$callback)
    Start-Process -wait -FilePath powershell $callback -verb runas
}

$name = 'joe'
RunElevated -callback @"
    Write-Host "I am running with elevated permissions $name"
    Read-Host Pause
"@
```

a -file method (there's no current directory):

```
start-process -wait powershell '-file c:\users\js\script.ps1 -name joe' -verb runas
```

Maybe this is it, but it needs the call operator.  The arguments are a string.

```
start-process -filepath powershell -args '& { param($name) Write-Host "I am running with elevated permissions $name" } -name joe; pause' -verb runas
```

Or since args can be a string array:

```
start-process -filepath powershell -args '&','{param($name) $name; pause}','-name joe' -verb runas
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work, but I'm not too keen on it b/c, in terms of maintainability (and readability -- syntax highlighting), I don't like the idea of having potentially large blocks of code represented as a plain text string. I guess the fundamental problem is a Powershell limitation. It's a shame that there is no true equivalent to sudo that lets you run just a single command with elevated permissions and right in the same shell session you're already in. Even better, if you have multiple commands that require sudo back-to-back, it won't re-prompt you. Would love that ability in powershell.